# Missing Constraints in Eclipse Plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to develop an Eclipse plugin using the most recent version of Eclipse for Java EE. I've set up a target platform with JavaSE-11 as the execution environment, I've created the plugin from a template with JavaSE-11 as the execution environment, and have ensured there is a JRE installed for JavaSE-11.

I am receiving [validation issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7MCb.png) when trying to run the plugin, and the following error text if I click Continue:

```
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
```

Where do I need to set this JRE in order for the configurator to resolve?

Comment: Is your Eclipse Application Launcher set to use Java 11?

Comment: What Java in set in the Run Configuration used by the launch as Eclipse Application?